# My react app on heroku opens home page but will not open other pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku, react-router

My react app runs fine locally, and deploys to heroku.  However, from the home page, any link to another page shows a blank page with 'not found' on it.  There are no other error messages.

Here is my server-side package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "portfolio-generator",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "12.16.x"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "concurrently": "^5.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "if-env": "^1.0.4",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.13",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.1",
    "react-bootstrap-validation": "^0.1.11",
    "styled-components": "^5.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "if-env NODE_ENV=production && npm run start:prod || npm run start:dev",
    "start:prod": "node server.js",
    "start:dev": "concurrently \"nodemon --ignore 'client/*'\" \"npm run client\"",
    "client": "cd client && npm run start",
    "build": "cd client && npm run build",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install && npm install --only=dev --no-shrinkwrap && npm run build",
    "seed": "node ./seeders/seed.js",
    "install": "cd client && npm install"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://https://github.com/...../jtsy.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://https://github.com/...../jtsy/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://https://github.com....../jtsy#readme"
}
```

Here's the client-side package.json:

```
{
  "name": "portfolio-generator",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3001/",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.1",
    "react-bootstrap-validation": "^0.1.11",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "semantic-ui-css": "^2.4.1",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^0.88.2",
    "styled-components": "^5.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

server.js

```
const express = require("express");
import npm package mongoose, the ODM for mongo database
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const routes = require("./routes");

const app = express();
// set the port for mongo connection to 3001 in development mode
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static("client/build"));
}

app.use(routes);

// Connect to the Mongo DB (portfolio_db)
mongoose.connect(
  process.env.MONGODB_URI || "mongodb://localhost/portfolio_db",
  {
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  }
);


app.listen(PORT, () =>
  console.log(`  ==> API Server now listening on PORT ${PORT}!`)
);
```

Based on some research, I added a static.json file:

```
{
  "root": "build/",
  "clean_urls": false,
  "routes": {
    "/**": "index.html"
  }
}
```

There is a default route in routes/index.js on the server side:

```
....
router.use("*", (req, res) =>
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../client/src/index.html"))
);

module.exports = router;
```

In App.js (react top component), react router is used like this:

```
...
     <Router>
        <Switch>
          <DevDataContext.Provider value={devDataProvider}>
            <SetupContext.Provider value={setupProvider}>
              {setup.initialized ? (
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
              ) : (
                  <Route exact path="/" component={Signin} />
                )}
              <Route exact path="/contact" component={Contact} />
              <Route exact path="/about" component={About} />
              <Route exact path="/Developer" component={Developer} />
              <Route exact path="/Signin" component={Signin} />
            </SetupContext.Provider>
          </DevDataContext.Provider>
          <Route component={NoMatch} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
   ...
```

With all that, I'm at a standstill.  The home page loads and refreshes, but won't redirect anywhere.

EDIT:  The path to index.html was wrong.  It resides in the 'public' folder under 'client', so in routes/index.js, it is now:

```
 router.use("*", (req, res) =>
      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../client/public/index.html"))
    );
```

Now all I get is a blank screen on the heroku page.  I assume my problem is based on how the routes are defined, but I still can't figure it out.

My folder structure is:

```
/projectname
  server.js
  package.json
  ...
 /client
    package.json
      /public
        index.html
        ...
      /src
        App.js
        index.js
        ...
          /components
          /pages
 /controllers
 /models
 /routes
    index.js (this is where the path to index.html is defined)
      /api
        index.js
        ...
```

EDIT #2 SOLUTION
Made a couple of key changes in server.js.  The most important was adding the 'path' package (rookie mistake).  I also had to put the 'app.use(routes)' ahead of the default react route code, which is now outside of the "production" code block.

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const routes = require("./routes");

const app = express();
// set the port for mongo connection to 3001 in development mode
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

// Configure body parsing for AJAX requests
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());

// Serve up static assets
**if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static("client/build"));
}
app.use(routes);
app.get("*", function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "./client/build/index.html"));
});**

// Connect to the Mongo DB (portfolio_db)
mongoose.connect(
  process.env.MONGODB_URI || "mongodb://localhost/portfolio_db",
  {
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  }
);

// Start the API server on port 3001
app.listen(PORT, () =>
  console.log(`  ==> API Server now listening on PORT ${PORT}!`)
);
```

I also removed the reference to the default react route in /routes/index.js

Comment: Is the not found from react router or the express app?

Comment: The message appears in the browser, so I assume it is in the react router.

Comment: You can see the network tab if your request returned 404 that would show "not found" for express apps as well.

Comment: Refreshing the home page shows no errors. When I try any other page,
I see 2 '400 Bad request' errors.  This is 1:  GET https://<appname>.herokuapp.com/%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico 400 (Bad Request)
The other is related to manifest.json.   These 2 errors also show in the console.
These are default files from create-react-app, and are in the /public folder.

Comment: Finally got it working.  I wasn't using the 'path' package in server.js.  See my edit to the original post.  Made a couple of other changes, too.

Answer (score 0):

Solution found.  3 changes to server.js.  Added:

```
const path = require('path')
```

Definitely a rookie mistake forgetting this!  Also, revised code to pull the default react route out of the "production" code block, and put it below 'app.use(routes), like:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static("client/build"));
}
app.use(routes);
app.get("*", function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "./client/build/index.html"));
});
```

I also removed the default react route from /routes/index.js.