# Cannot GET /path on page reload in MERN app after heroku deployment

Tags: reactjs, express, heroku, mern

I deployed my mern app on heroku, when i click on different route, the page changes.However, when i reload the page, It shows 'Cannot GET /path/'. I have tried some answers on stack overflow but it was not working for me.

This is what i Have in my app.js file,

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static('client/build'));

  app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    let filePath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'client/build', 'index.html');

    res.sendFile(filePath);
  });
}
```

One of the answers on stackOverflow recommended changing '/' to '/*' in app.get but when i tried it, I was able to reload the page but my api endpoints stop working.

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
      app.use(express.static('client/build'));
    
      app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
        let filePath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'client/build', 'index.html');
    
        res.sendFile(filePath);
      });
    }
```

This is how i set up my routes

```
app.use('/api/v1/carers', carerRoutes);
app.use('/api/v1/task', taskRoutes)
```

This is my folder structure, all the files is stored in 'server' folder, 'client' is the frontend
[image]

What am i doing wrongly? I need help, please

My react frontend route. N.B the admin route is nested. it has the 'carer' route within it.

```
<Route path="admin/*"
            element={
              <ProtectedRoute
                isAllowed={!!currentUser && currentUser.role === 'admin'}
                redirectPath="/signin"
              >
                {' '}
                <AdminHomePage />
              </ProtectedRoute>
            }
          />

          <Route path="signin" element={<SignIn />} />
    </Routes>
```

Comment: i used '/path' as an example. This is the actual message: 'Cannot GET /admin/carers' @HeikoTheißen

Comment: Your code does not contain a route for `GET /admin/carers`, only for `GET /api/v1/carers`.

Comment: GET '/admin/carers' is my react app routing while 'GET /api/v1/carers' is the endpoint. This is the first time i am building with MERN app, maybe i am doing something wrong.  I am going to add my react route in the edited post. @HeikoTheißen

Comment: @HeikoTheißen, I have been able to solve the problem by following the answer in this link. [link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61858183/how-can-i-get-my-mern-app-to-refresh-correctly-on-heroku